# xargs with head -n

Tags: bash, xargs

I am trying to write a command which takes a random line from a CSV and outputs that line minus 5. Say, it outputs line 50, then it should print from 46 to 50 both included. I can achieve this in two steps, however when trying to use "xargs" to pass the line number to the following command (head -n) I got an error saying: `"head: invalid number of lines: ‘{}’"`.
My command is:

```
cat test.csv |  awk '{ print NR }' | shuf -n 1 | xargs -l head -n "{}" test.csv | tail -n 5
```

Where `"xargs -l head -n "{}" test.csv"` should collect the number from the `"shuf"` function and then tail it to 5 to grab the last 5 rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote from the xargs man page:

> -I replace-str
>
> Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names
> read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate
> input items; instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies
> -x and -L 1.

As you can see, the -I flag is necessary to specify the replacement string for your command.

Without the specified string, the xargs will simply append the value of each line to the end of your command. So the following should work:

```
cat test.csv |  awk '{ print NR }' | shuf -n 1 | xargs -I {} head -n "{}" test.csv | tail -n 5
```